# What's the recommended way to deploy a Google App Engine Flexible app to replace a previous version?

Tags: app-engine-flexible

My previous experience is with Heroku. When we deploy to heroku, that service automatically stops the previous version of the app and replaces it with the new version.

So far on Google App Engine Flexible, I don't see an easy way to deploy like this.

I have run `gcloud app deploy --stop-previous-version --promote`

But I get the error `Error Response: [400] The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES`

....which suggests to me that this `deploy` command is not stopping the previous versions or instances.

It would seem that the old version of the app continues running, and I would have to fiddle with the web interface each time to stop previous version?

Comment: When you use "gcloud app deploy" it will by default stop the previous version after the latest version has been deployed and all the traffic has been migrated to the new version.
Can you check the quota limit of In-use IP addresses 
: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=Your-Project&service=compute.googleapis.com&usage=USED

For more info: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that if you don't specify versions during deployment, it will use timestamp as version number. And the newly deployed version is automatically serving. Previous version will be stopped.[image]

Another thing to be aware of is that this method will cause app engine attempt to build a new container every time which could take a long time. I suggest you use --version=dev for dev purpose otherwise expect a very long deployment time for bigger projects.

Answer (score 0):

The error may relate to you having too many versions which end up taking your addresses quota. Try to delete some versions through the web UI.

The `--promote` is true by default, you need to pass in `--no-promote` if you ***do not*** want to promote it.